# Inventory stock calculation query or/and optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, optimization

`Remains` - all transactions of products

`Stock`   - Stock of products

`DimDate`  - Time table

**Calculation of stock:**

1. take the date for which needed calculate stock, example date `20050115` product -`1` warehouse - `6`
2. take next month first day example `20050201` and from `Stock` table take one row with `weight`, `stock`, `cost` for the same product and warehouse.
3. Sum all transactions in `Remains` from selected date till month end and subtract from taken row of `Stock` table

For first day next month I'm using this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime)))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime))),112)
```

Example `Remains`:

```
|  TIMEKEY | PRODUCT | WAREHOUSE | COST | STOCK | WEIGHT |
|----------|---------|-----------|------|-------|--------|
| 20050114 |       1 |         6 |  100 |     5 |     15 |
| 20050118 |       1 |         6 |  200 |    10 |     30 |
| 20050125 |       1 |         6 | -100 |    -5 |    -15 |
```

`Stock`:

```
|  TIMEKEY | PRODUCT | WAREHOUSE | COST | STOCK | WEIGHT |
|----------|---------|-----------|------|-------|--------|
| 20050201 |       1 |         6 |  515 |    55 |     53 |
| 20050301 |       2 |         8 |   20 |     3 |      2 |
| 20050301 |       3 |         9 |   16 |     2 |      3 |
| 20050301 |       4 |        10 |   49 |     8 |      5 |
| 20050401 |       5 |        26 |   59 |     9 |     10 |
```

Result (my query) calculated stock by day for product 1, warehouse 6 and first month:

```
|  DATEKEY | PRODUCT | WAREHOUSE | WEIGHT |  STOCK |   COST |
|----------|---------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
| 20050101 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050102 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050103 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050104 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050105 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050106 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050107 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050108 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050109 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050110 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050111 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050112 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050113 |       1 |         6 |     23 |     45 |    315 |
| 20050114 |       1 |         6 |     38 |     50 |    415 |
| 20050115 |       1 |         6 |     38 |     50 |    415 |
| 20050116 |       1 |         6 |     38 |     50 |    415 |
| 20050117 |       1 |         6 |     38 |     50 |    415 |
| 20050118 |       1 |         6 |     68 |     60 |    615 |
| 20050119 |       1 |         6 |     68 |     60 |    615 |
| 20050120 |       1 |         6 |     68 |     60 |    615 |
| 20050121 |       1 |         6 |     68 |     60 |    615 |
| 20050122 |       1 |         6 |     68 |     60 |    615 |
| 20050123 |       1 |         6 |     68 |     60 |    615 |
| 20050124 |       1 |         6 |     68 |     60 |    615 |
```

**Problem / Question**
The stock of product is not ended so I need to show result for full month(or the range I select in where clause), not just till 24 day. IF this immpossible, maybe somebody could help with current query optimization I'm using for calculation stock. I'm Using ms sql 2008r2

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad49d/6)**

```
SELECT t.DateKey, r.Product, r.Warehouse,
(SELECT [Weight]
FROM Stock
WHERE Timekey = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime)))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime))),112)
AND Product = r.Product
AND Warehouse = r.Warehouse)-SUM(r.Weight) AS [Weight],
(SELECT Stock
FROM Stock
WHERE Timekey = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime)))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime))),112)
AND Product = r.Product
AND Warehouse = r.Warehouse)-SUM(Stock) as Stock,
(SELECT Cost
FROM Stock
WHERE Timekey = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime)))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime))),112)
AND Product = r.Product
AND Warehouse = r.Warehouse)-SUM(Cost) AS Cost
FROM DimDate t, Remains r
WHERE t.DateKey < r.Timekey
AND r.Timekey <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime)))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(convert(varchar,t.DateKey) as datetime))),112)
AND t.DateKey >= 20050101
and r.Product = '1'
and r.Warehouse = 6
GROUP BY t.DateKey, r.Product, r.Warehouse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell if it's faster on a small data set, but the following looks to have a much better query plan. The approach is to only join on to the stock table once instead of three times.

```
with x as (
    select
        t.DateKey, 
        r.Product, 
        r.Warehouse, 
        sum(r.Weight) as Weight,
        sum(Stock) as Stock,
        sum(Cost) as Cost,
        (t.DateKey / 100 
            + Case t.DateKey / 100 % 100 when 12 Then 89 else 1 end) 
            * 100 + 1 as TimeKey
    from
        DimDate t, 
        Remains r
    where
        t.DateKey < r.Timekey and 
        r.Timekey <= (
            t.DateKey / 100 
                + Case t.DateKey / 100 % 100 when 12 Then 89 else 1 end) 
                * 100 + 1 and 
        t.DateKey >= 20050101 and 
        r.Product = 1 and 
        r.Warehouse = 6
    group by
        t.DateKey, 
        r.Product, 
        r.Warehouse
) select
    x.DateKey,
    x.Product,
    x.Warehouse,
    s.Weight - x.Weight as Weight,
    s.Stock - x.Stock as Stock,
    s.Cost - x.Cost as Cost
From
    x
        left outer join
    Stock s
        on s.TimeKey = x.TimeKey and
           s.Product = x.Product and
           s.Warehouse = x.Warehouse;
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad49d/9)</kbd>**

if you have the chance to redesign this schema, bear in mind that the date datatype only uses three bytes, compared to four for an int.

It's probably not contributing much to the overall query cost, but you could store the "start of next month" value as a computed column on the DimDate table. It makes the query a bit easier to read.

```
create table DimDate (
    [DateKey] int,
    StartOfNextMonthKey as (
            DateKey / 100 
            + Case DateKey / 100 % 100 when 12 Then 89 else 1 end
        ) * 100 + 1 persisted
);
```

then the query is

```
with x as (
    select
        t.DateKey, 
        r.Product, 
        r.Warehouse, 
        sum(r.Weight) AS [Weight],
        sum(Stock) as Stock,
        sum(Cost) AS Cost,
        t.StartOfNextMonthKey
    from
        DimDate t, 
        Remains r
    where
        t.DateKey < r.Timekey AND 
        r.Timekey <= t.StartOfNextMonthKey and 
        t.DateKey >= 20050101 and 
        r.Product = 1 and 
        r.Warehouse = 6
    group by
        t.DateKey, 
        r.Product, 
        r.Warehouse,
        t.StartOfNextMonthKey
) select
    x.DateKey,
    x.Product,
    x.Warehouse,
    s.Weight - x.Weight as Weight,
    s.Stock - x.Stock as Stock,
    s.Cost - x.Cost as Cost
From
    x
        left outer join
    Stock s
        on s.TimeKey = x.StartOfNextMonthKey and
           s.Product = x.Product and
           s.Warehouse = x.Warehouse;
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63d19/7)</kbd>**